# Why is ECC (Eliptical Curve) an `--expert` feature in PGP?

Tags: pgp, cipher-selection

Eleptial Curve is now included in PGP. However when I run `gpg2 --full-gen-key`, I get

```
Please select what kind of key you want:
   (1) RSA and RSA (default)
   (2) DSA and Elgamal
   (3) DSA (sign only)
   (4) RSA (sign only)
  (14) Existing key from card
```

It's only when I run it with `gpg2 --full-gen-key --expert` that I get the option to generate an ECC key,

```
Please select what kind of key you want:
   (1) RSA and RSA (default)
   (2) DSA and Elgamal
   (3) DSA (sign only)
   (4) RSA (sign only)
   (7) DSA (set your own capabilities)
   (8) RSA (set your own capabilities)
   (9) ECC and ECC
  (10) ECC (sign only)
  (11) ECC (set your own capabilities)
  (13) Existing key
  (14) Existing key from card
```

Why is that ECC is only available as an `--expert` feature in PGP? [You can see this code in the latest version of GPG v2.2.40](https://github.com/gpg/gnupg/blob/STABLE-BRANCH-2-2.40/g10/keygen.c#L2014). The documentation doesn't just not say it's an export feature, but [it says it's the default](https://wiki.gnupg.org/ECC)

> GnuPG supports ECC since version 2.1 and creates ECC keypairs by default since version 2.3.

Comment: *"and creates ECC keypairs by default __since version 2.3__. ..."* - and the version you are using is what? Check with `gpg --version` *" You can see this code in the latest version of __GPG v2.2.40__"* - the latest ist not 2.2.40 but 2.4 - see https://github.com/gpg/gnupg/blob/STABLE-BRANCH-2-4/g10/keygen.c

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm using gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.40 That's a good catch. If you want to expand that I'll mark it as chosen. But it is weird that it's still an expert feature in gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GnuPG 2.2 was released in 2017. It was the first stable release which supports ECC in PGP  (2.1 was a developer version). The relevant standard [RFC 6637](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6637) was released in 2012. Since standards are often slow to take off one could not expect that the majority of PGP implementations in the wild already supported ECC keys. But if the communication peer does not support ECC keys, it is probably not a good idea to use these.

To maintain interoperability was the existing software stack in the wild it makes therefore sense to hide creation of such key behind some expert flag for a while, i.e. make it available only for users who hopefully educated themselves enough to know what they are doing and specifically what impact using ECC keys might have regarding communication with others. And it is common that minor software versions don't introduce major behavior changes, so this decision was kept for every 2.2.* release.

When version 2.4 was released in 2022 the situation looked different: support for ECC keys was much more available now in the wild - for example all the users of version 2.2 could handle such keys even though creation of such keys was hidden behind an expert flag. Thus it made sense to switch to the more modern algorithms by default now.